# Including an Ant build script from actual parent directory of a linked directory

Tags: java, macos, ant, build

I have a problem including an Ant build script from a parent directory. Because I need to develop a custom component for a 3rd party software, I have a project directory structure set up as follows:

```
/repos/HG REPO/Component  // repo for my component
/repos/GIT REPO/contrib/contrib-build.xml  // 3rd party software repo & build script
/repos/GIT REPO/contrib/[symlink to Component]/build.xml // My components build script
```

Now I need to import contrib-build.xml from build.xml, so in build.xml I would use:

```
<import file="../contrib-build.xml"/>
```

However, this causes error as it tries to find the file from

```
/repos/HG REPO/contrib-build.xml
```

How can I access the file without giving an absolute path for the import file argument? If I take that path then one would have to manually remember to set it on another dev setup.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried?

```
<import file="../../GIT REPO/contrib/contrib-build.xml"/>
```

Comment: It will work locally, if i do "../../../../Path from root relative to both repos/contrib.build.xml". Of course this is just as specific to my directory structure as using absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

The error is folder naming.
Ant does not allow space inside directory name.
Try to change

```
/repos/HG_REPO/contrib.build.xml
```

instead of

```
/repos/HG REPO/contrib.build.xml
```

Comment: I did not actually name the folder "HG REPO", that is just an abstraction to simplify explaining the problem. :)

Comment: Yeah I only want you to check your directory name..For not including space